# How to use k fold cross validation for CNN keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm implementing CNN for multi-classification using keras. Model is performing well on training data but having very low validation accuracy.
There is an over-fitting problem. Please guide how can I reduce over-fitting using K-fold cross validation. How to apply cross validation for this code.

```py
embedding_layer = w2v_model_wv.wv.get_keras_embedding()
sequence_input = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
x = Conv1D(filters=nb_filters, kernel_size=n_gram, padding='valid', 
activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vecsize))(embedded_sequences)
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=maxlen - n_gram + 1)(x)
x= Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x= Dropout(0.5)(x)
preds = Dense(nb_labels, activation=final_activation, 
kernel_regularizer=l2(dense_wl2reg), bias_regularizer=l2(dense_bl2reg))(x)

classlabels, x_train, y_train = convert_trainingdata(trainclassdict)

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)
x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
x_train = pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)

model = Model(sequence_input, preds)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format('cnn_deepnn'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics= 
['acc'])
model.fit(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), validation_split=0.2, 
epochs=1700, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Comment: Your premise is wrong, you don't reduce overfitting with k-fold cross-validation.

Comment: then how can I ?

Comment: Dropout before and after Maxpooling?! Why? Remove that one before Maxpooling. And, try to use BatchNormalization. It might help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Matias Valdenegro, K-fold is not the right approach.
You can reduce overfitting by:

1) Adding **more data**
2) **Augment**ing your data.  This can be tricky when working with text data, but I've had luck with resampling data while dropping nonessential words (adverbs/adj)
3) **Regularization** methods (Good you're using Dropout. Try working with kernel Regularizer within the Conv1D function)
4) I would experiment with adding **more layers**.